# Is there an apple API to unlink apple ID on apps?

Tags: ios

my app is using an apple id authentication. And I want to make a sign-out system, so I want to use an apple API in nodeJS(express) to unlink the users from my app. Is there an API in apple for this?
I want to get an effect of pressing the button 'Stop Using Apple ID' of the screenshot by using an API. is there an API for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unE08.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiED4.png)

this is done in https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage